# jQuery Validate classrules not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Why doesn't it work to define classrules like documented in the jquery.validator documentation?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/testit1234/MLDhM/)

My javascript

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('foo', {
    required: true,
    digits: true
});
jQuery('#test').validate({
    rules: {
        field: 'foo'
    }
});
```

My html

```
<form id="test">
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Think about the confusion of future readers who see an accepted answer telling you to add a `name` attribute to an element that already contains a `name` attribute.  If you don't want to accept the technically correct answer, at least post your own and accept that instead.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring your original jsFiddle, this answer simply answers the question with the code as it's posted.

The code in your OP, using the `addClassRules` method, requires that you use the `class` attribute within the input element...

**HTML**:

```
<form id="test">
    <input name="field" type="text" class="foo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('foo', {
    required: true,
    digits: true
});

jQuery('#test').validate({
    // your other options
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/G4rb3/1/**

Answer (score 2):

Your `input` fields **MUST** have the `name` attribute to work with the Validate plugin. It's missing in your fiddle.

`<input id="2" name="numberVal" class="numberVal" type="text" />`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrhBr/98/)

Comment: I don't get your point. You have my fiddle and code above, could you edit it as stated in your post?

Comment: I attached the wrong fiddle, sorry. This is my markup, where shall I add a name attribute? There is just one input field? <input name="field" type="text">

Comment: @junior, check your jsFiddle.  It does not match your OP... which one do you want fixed?

Comment: I totally messed up the post. The correct fiddle is updated in my post now.

Comment: @junior, this answer is correct but also has nothing to do with the code in your question and jsFiddle.  The future reader is going to be really lost since there's already a `name` attribute in the OP.